# Fill na cells in one column with another column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Given an excel sample data as follows:

[image]

For `NA` cells in column B (which means `B3` and `B5`), I'll need to fill with values in column `A`.

[image]

I write a simple formula for cell B3: `=IF(ISNA(B3),A3,B3)` (equivalent to `df['b'].fillna(df['a'])` in Pandas), but returns `0`. How could I write a proper formula to solve this issue? Thanks.

The expected result should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cell can contain either a value or a formula, which is why you should create an extra column for the result. NA in excel is an error code and does not indicate that a cell is blank. You should use the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(B3),A3,B3)` in column C

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the "Circular dependency detected" error.
The easy solution is:

1. copy the column b in the column c
2. fill the na value in the column c with the formula that you defined

Comment: I tested, it returns 0 as well, seems we should use `ISBLANK()` instead of `ISNA()` as @tnavidi suggested.